# Javascript fundamental

Tags: javascript

I've read "JavaScript. The Core by Dmitry Soshnikov" and i don't understand very well this code (refactoring). Why k is increment ?

```
var data = [];

for (var k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
  data[k] = (function () {
    console.log(k);
  })(k)
}

data[0];
data[1];
data[2];
```

this portion of code :

```
(function () {
    console.log(k);
})(k)
```

So when we add a parameter (k) to the end of a function, if i understand well, the value (k) is take from the current context/scope ?

Comment: That code would *work* but it doesn't make much sense as an example; it doesn't do anything. The array will be populated with `undefined` because the function returns nothing.

Comment: ... nor does it accept any arguments

Comment: ... and therefore would be exactly the same with `()` as with `(k)`.

Comment: @Pointy: it does do something.  It logs the values to the console and fills the array with three `undefined`s.  But this is very odd.  I haven't yet looked at that book, so I don't know what it's trying to show here, but I know the author knows his stuff.

Comment: The code posted here does not appear in the article referenced. Code *like* the posted code appears, but not exactly this code. The examples in the article do make sense.

Comment: Ok i understand. It's an auto execute function : IIFE !